# Carregar imagem do servidor em uma ImageView

Tags: android

Eu estou pegando as informações do banco via `WebService`, e pego o caminho da imagem que está no servidor.
Essa imagem eu tenho que carregar em um `ListView`, para isso eu faço um `AssyncTask` dentro da minha `Adapter`, porem não busca as imagens porque ele chama a `AssyncTask` 6 vezes, sendo que tem 2 imagens cadastradas só, o que eu tenho que fazer, abaixo segue os codigos.

```
public class PesquisaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Produto> listaProdutos;
    // private List<Loja> listaLojas;
    // private List<Marca> listaMarcas;
    private final Activity activity;
    Dados dados = new Dados();

    ImageView imagemProduto;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    public PesquisaAdapter(List<Produto> produtos, Activity activity) {
        this.listaProdutos = produtos;
        // this.listaLojas = lojas;
        // this.listaMarcas = marcas;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicao, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View layout = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.item_pesquisar, null);

        Produto produto = listaProdutos.get(posicao);
        // Loja loja = listaLojas.get(posicao);
        // Marca marca = listaMarcas.get(posicao);

        imagemProduto = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.item_pesquisa_img);
        TextView descricaoProduto = (TextView) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.item_pesquisa_descricaoproduto);
        TextView descricaoMarca = (TextView) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.item_pesquisa_descricaomarca);
        TextView nomeLoja = (TextView) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.item_pesquisa_nomeloja);

        descricaoProduto.setText(produto.getDescricao());
        // nomeLoja.setText(loja.getNomeFantasia());



        carregarImagem(produto.getUrlImagem());
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listaProdutos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicao) {
        return listaProdutos.get(posicao);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicao) {
        return listaProdutos.get(posicao).getIdMarca();
    }

    public void carregarImagem(String urlImagem) {
        new CarregaImagemTask().execute(dados.endereco + "app/webroot/img/up/"
                + urlImagem);
    }

    public class CarregaImagemTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // progress = ProgressDialog.show(PesquisarActivity.this,
            // "Aguarde...", "Carregando Imagens...", true, true);
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String urlString = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                conexao.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conexao.setDoInput(true);
                conexao.connect();

                InputStream is = conexao.getInputStream();
                Bitmap imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                return imagem;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //progress.dismiss();
            if (result != null) {
                Bitmap imagemReduzida = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 150, 150, true);
                imagemProduto.setImageBitmap(imagemReduzida);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque não usa alguma biblioteca especializada em carregamento de imagens? Eles são feitos para esse tipo de requisito. Dê uma olhada nessa lista (https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) e escolha um. Recomendo o `Picasso` ou `Universal Image Loader`.

Answer (score -1):

Bem eu tive que desenvolver algo parecido para a faculdade, então para isso eu pesquisei e escolhi e lib Volley (que é recomendada pelo Google) para fazer esse carregamento assíncrono de imagens. 
Recomendo que você veja este vídeo [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gO-LXXbUCBk), ele monstra como carregar a imagem tanto em um ImageView como em um NetWorkImageView.
Espero que tenha te ajudado.